# How to use org-refile with helm to create a new node?

Tags: org-mode, helm

I'm trying to use Helm with org-refile. It looks like everyting is working properly except one thing.

For example, I have the following tree in my org file:

```
* Top level 1
** Example heading
* Top level 2
```

I want to refile "Example heading" to a new node under "Top level 2". Result should look like this:

```
* Top level 1
* Top level 2
** New node
*** Example heading
```

I already setup org-mode so it creates new node without any issues. The problem is that Helm doesn't provide any completion, so every time I should type the whole string, then I need to add "/New node" and press Enter.

I tried to use Control-Z which works fine when finding files, but not in org-refile. Is there a way to solve such issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem is that Helm doesn't provide any completion, so every time I should type the whole string, then I need to add "/New node" and press Enter.

If I understand correctly, you means when your input pattern includes "/New node", for example, "lev 2/New node", this won't work (which is expected), you should use "Top level 2/New node" as your input pattern before <kbd>RET</kbd>, but you don't have to type "Top level 2" by yourself, just use <kbd>C-c C-y</kbd> (`helm-yank-selection`) to insert current selected candidate to do that for you, for example, for your case, all you need to do is:

<kbd>C-c C-w</kbd> lev 2 <kbd>C-c C-y</kbd> /New Node <kbd>RET</kbd>